# Multiply a cell by a value only if it's greater than value contained in another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following set up.

[image]

I want a formula to put in the "Profit" cell.  For I5 this would calculated such that Profit = (G5 * D5) + (H5 * D5) but only if G5 is less than or equal to B5 and H5 is less than or equal to C5.

I know I can use a complicated nested if statement, but I'm wondering if there is a more parsimonious way of doing this.

Based on the first answer, I forgot to mention this condition:

In the event that this condition `AND($G5<=$B5, $H5<=$C5)' is not satisfied, then you should simply check the individual conditions. So if G5 <= B5 but H5 is NOT <= C5, then the "Profit" is simply G5 * D5

Comment: Then you can't get anything from that.  The left side is a willingness-to-pay, the right side is the price.  If the price > willingness-to-pay, that's zero profit from that item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
   =IF(AND($G5<=$B5, $H5<=$C5), $G5*$D5+$H5*$D5, "")
```

Or you can put a zero instead of the empty string if that's more appropriate.

**UPDATE**

```
=($G5*$D5)*($G5<=$B5)+($H5*$D5)*($H5<=$C5)
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that, in the event that this condition `AND($G5<=$B5, $H5<=$C5)' is not satisfied, then you should simply check the individual condtions.  So if G5 <= B5 but H5 is NOT <= C5, then the "Profit" is simply G5 * D5